# Separate Google Analytics users by feature set of A/B test?

Tags: google-analytics

I am performing a series of A/B testing on my site through an A/B split test engine.

I've designed my site to use url arguments to enable and disable features. For example, `www.example.com?entryDialog=1` will turn the feature "Entry Dialog" on.

I am trying to use Google Analytics to study the effects of features on users. However, I am not sure what's the best way to do this.

Right now, I am using

```
ga('create', 'UA-myid-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

to send a pageview.

According to the documentation on pageview, I have only title, location and page for this call.

How can I add an additional parameter "feature" to pageview such that I can segment my GA reporting by features?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You're wanting **custom dimensions and metrics** https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets

```
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension15':  'My Custom Dimension'
});
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {
  'metric18': 8000
});
ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {
  'metric19': 24.99
});
```